# Can I distinguish between requests coming from different tabs of same browser?

Tags: c#-3.0, browser

I need to work on a requirement where if a user has logged into my application from a browser (IE8/9 or Firefox) and he opens a **new tab of the same browser** and logs in again, then my application should log out the user from previous tab.

Comment: @SteveB well I need not necessarily logout the usser, the major issue is that my application saves user's context information, like which all modules he has opened etc. on server, and if user opens same module in two tabs the information is overwritten by both the tabs which results in incorrect context being saved sometimes.

Comment: not sure if it will works, but I suspect that if you use cookieless session, you may achieve your goal. When using cookieless session, the session id is append to the url. So multiples tabs will have their own url. However, you may reconsider your requirement.... this seems a bit "unusual" (but I don't have the whole picture).

Comment: how about showing a warning in the new tab that the user is already in a session. That way you don't have to worry about it. Microsoft does this also with their outlook webmail.